# MVC File upload Where to put code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

OK, so I am trying to make the move to MVC.
I have a Model, view and Controller made, but now I want to change the create functionality of the app.

I am working with uploads and I have this system generated code in my contoller.

```
Function Create(<Bind(Include:="Id,Course,Category,SubCategory,FileName,FileType,UploadedBy,DateUploaded")> ByVal acAsset As acAsset) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.Assets.Add(acAsset)
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If
        Return View(acAsset)
    End Function
```

Now I want to change this so that it will

1. Check for the existence of a folder for Course, Category and Sub category.  If this folder is not there it must be created.
2. Upload the file select by a file selection box.
3. Post the files' name to the db.

The code is not necessarily the issue, I am jut not sure where I should put in the controller?

I have read this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/) but is not dealing with the DB post.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add your code in controller that you want to hit on button click

**Your Razor View Code**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    { 
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
    }
```

**C# Code**

```
 [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
   {
       if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
       {
           var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
           var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
           file.SaveAs(path);
       }

       return RedirectToAction("UploadDocument");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your View

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

In your Controller

```
public actionresult(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    string contentType = file.ContentType;
    using (Stream fs = file.InputStream)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
        }
    }
 //Data Context Code here 
  tableName.File= bytes;
  db.add(tableName);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```